# Cylindrical shells and disk method gives different results

Tags: calculus

Volume of solid generated by revolving region bounded by lines $x=0$ , $y=1$ and curve $y=\sqrt {x}$ about line y=1

In shells method i set up integral as

$\int_{0}^{1}2\pi y^3dy$

Using disk method i set up as

$\int_{0}^{1} \pi (\sqrt x - 1)^2dx$

I would like to know where i am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Shells should be $\int_0^1 2\pi y^2(1-y)\,dy$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas why so ?

Comment: You understand the $y^2$ part, so I will only deal with the $1-y$. Take a thin strip at height $y$. When this is rotated about $y=1$, the cylindrical shell has radius $1-y$. Small when $y$ is close to $1$, biggish when $y$ is close to $0$. Your $(y^2)(y)$ would have been correct for rotation about the $x$-axis.

Comment: You  are welcome.